# jQuery File Upload (Show uploaded images)

Tags: java, php, jquery, mysql

I'm creating a CMS platform with php & MySql.
Ι'm using [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) in order to upload images in the server and the database. 
The problem is that the uploader shows all the images of the folder. 
I want to show only images with a specific id from the database.
How can i do this with java?

HERE IS THE CODE

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">



{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>


        <td>
        <p class="title"><strong>{%=file.title||''%}</strong></p>
<p class="description">{%=file.description||''%}</p>
            <p class="name">
                {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}

        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, java? if you want to do something in JAVA, then why have you tagged this with php?

Comment: I said that because the function to show uploaded images is in java.